# Uploading file to the cloud using cloudmanic-storage

Tags: codeigniter, rackspace-cloud

I'm trying to upload my files from the server to the CDN by using codeigniter and the cloudmanic-storage library. The functions for creating/listing containers work, but the one for adding files to the container does not.

I have no idea what is wrong with it or how to fix this issues, so if anyone has come along this problem it will be great to share some knowledge :)

```
$container = 'cm-storage-' . time();
    echo '<h1>Create test container.</h1>';
    $this->storage->create_container($container, 'private');
    echo "New container: <b>$container</b><br /><br />";
    echo '<hr />';
            $file = "_data/articlepics/big_".$config['file_name'];
    $this->storage->upload_file($container, $file, 'test01.jpg');
```

I'm sure that the file that I'm trying to upload exists, the problem also persists when i try it out with the example controller. It just doesn't want to upload the files to the CDN for some reason.

Codeigniter ver.2.0.2
Latest cloudmanic-storage from github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the type hasn't been defined and the guess function has trouble guessing what the file is.

What I did is to sort out the files when uploading/resizing the files in the controller and then (after i know the extension) just add the file type to the `rackspace_rc_driver.php`

```
function upload_file($cont, $path, $name, $type = NULL, $acl = 'private', $metadata = array())
    {
```

**$type="image/jpeg";**

```
$my_container = $this->_conn->get_container($cont);

        // move local file to server        
        $my_object = $my_container->create_object($name);

        // If we pass in a type we don't try to guess the type.
        if(! is_null($type))
        {
            $my_object->content_type = $type;
        }
        //echo $path;die();
        $my_object->load_from_filename($path);

        return ($my_object->container->cdn_enabled) ? $my_object->container->cdn_uri . '/' . $my_object->name : $my_object->name;
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else.